# Related to Customization?

Tags: sharing

In a scenario there are two users one is p1 and p2. What I want is when any users of these create a record in object the other user must not see that. We have to do this by putting the sharing rule as public to that object in the sharing settings.

Tell me that it is possible are not. Give your suggestions.

Comment: Not entirely clear what you are asking, but if you want p1 to see the record he created, but p2 not, just set the **OWD** settings of your object to **private**.

Answer (score 3):

Its really important that you understand the OWD in Salesforce properly. Since you have set the OWD of object to 'Public' it means that any User, be it User1, User2, User3...UserN, will be able to see records created by any other User.

While setting the baseline, here are the 3 question that you should ask

1. Who is the most restricted User?
2. Should he be able to see all records? No - PRIVATE; Yes - Next Question
3. Should he be able to modify all records? No - PUBLIC READONLY, Yes - PUBLIC Read/Write

Also please note that sharing rules are used to expand the baseline OWD and not limit them. In your case OWD for corresponding Object should be Private as Answer to Q2 goes NO.

Some Links for reference : 
https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=managing_the_sharing_model.htm&language=en_US 
http://www.shellblack.com/administration/owds/ 
http://www.crmsalesforcetraining.com/organization-wide-default-in-salesforce-owd-settings-in-sfdc/

Comment: This is a good answer. It would be a very good answer if you would link to some of the doc URLs. Just a thought.

Comment: Added some , Please feel free to add/remove.